# Invalid Property Value for combobox

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, userform

I am experiencing an issue in my `userform`. I have a number `comboboxes` which is drawing its `rowsource` from respective named ranges.

If I go into the userform and click submit without selecting that combobox I have no issues and all goes through brilliantly. If the named range is selected but left blank then when I click submit I receive the error "Invalid Property Value". I already know that this is linked to "Match Required" = True. My question however. Is there a way I can stop this error showing and the form to submit if a combobox is selected but left blank?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but didn't understand your question

Comment: I think he just wants to skip over the error

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like so, for your population, adding a null value

```
Dim a() As Variant

Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = ""

a = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("testing").Range("testrng").Value)

Me.ComboBox1.List = Split(vbNullString & "," & Join(a, ","), ",")
```